# Dynamic Bandwidth Allocation

Tags: networking, routing, bandwidth

My days in networking are too far behind me to remember, so I thought I'd come here!  I'm setting up a network of 10 devices, and I'd like to dynamically limit the bandwidth available to each one as demand changes on the network.

For example: If only 1 device were active, it would receive the lion's share of the network, but if many devices were online and active, the allocation of available bandwidth would be shared "equally" between them.

Any insight would be great :)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This sounds a perfect case for using a third-party firmware on the router.  Most firmware out of the box that comes with routers today wouldn't have anything like this though.

Answer (score 1):

What your asking about is typically referred to QoS or Quality of Service rules. SOHO equipment tends to have limited bordering on useless QoS features so you may want to purchase pro-sumer or above grade gear.

Bear in mind there are a few policies, hard limits(Everyone gets 4Mb if possible), Proportional (Everyone gets Total/NumUsers leased) or burstable where clients can consume a lot for 2-3 seconds then are curtailed (20Mb for 2s then 4Mb sustained). The latter is sometimes more costly to implement but tends to lead to a very strong user experience as pages load quickly but nobody can "bandwidth hog".